# Не пишется текст в ячейке TableView

Tags: c++, qt

У меня проблема, не пишется текст в ячейке TableView. Мне нужно чтобы после нажатия на кнопку у меня добавился текст в ячейку. Но он не  добавляется.

У меня две кнопки и я в функции смотрю которую я нажал и от этого должен добавляться разный текст.
Я делаю так:

```
 void TableModel::insertComponent(Type type)
 {
    if(type == CATEGORY)
    {
       std::unique_ptr<Category> category(new Category("Новая категория"));
       mCompositeComponent->addChild(std::move(category));
       this->insertRows(this->rowCount(), 1);
    }

    if(type == TEST)
    {
       std::unique_ptr<Test> test(new Test("Новый текст"));
       mCompositeComponent->addChild(std::move(test));
       this->insertRows(this->rowCount(), 1);
    }
  }
```

В `data` я добавляю `name`.

```
  QVariant TableModel::data(const QModelIndex& index, int role) const
  {
    const int row = index.row();
    const int col = index.column();

    if (role == Qt::DisplayRole)
    {
      const Component* component = mCompositeComponent->child(row);
      return QString(component->name());
    }
    return QVariant();
  }
```

И сама обработка кнопок:

```
  void Widget::addCategoryClicked()
  {
      mTableModel->insertComponent(CATEGORY);
  }
  void Widget::addTestClicked()
  {
     mTableModel->insertComponent(TEST);
  }
```

Comment: может функцию я не использую какуету?  неужели никто не знает как сделать чтобы перерисовалася таблица

Comment: `setData` переопределен?

Comment: @gil9red нет. а что я там  должен делать?

Comment: я по этом примере  делаю - http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/modelview.html

Comment: Там вы меняете значение в своей структуре данных -- mCompositeComponent. Когда вы редактировали значение в view, вызывался метод setData вашей модели и если вы не меняли через него данные своей структуры, то, конечно, ничего не изменится

Comment: @gil9red я  же правильно передаю свой текст  чтобы  записать в  таблицу: this->insertRows(this->rowCount(), 1); может тут я что то не то  делаю?

Comment: думаю да, если новая запись появляется, то правильно

Comment: @gil9red но я  же не меняю значения. я  хочу просто  записать  значения  шаблоное в ячейку

Comment: @gil9red нет не появляется. Я не писал свою функию  insertRows
 а взял стандартную. И вызываю ее в своей функции

Comment: Понятно. Используйте в insertComponent методы `beginInsertRows(QModelIndex(), row, row);` и `endInsertRows();`, которые уведомлят о добавлении данных, пример: https://github.com/gil9red/CardPreview/blob/7a52806abb3eb457c252c57955e389e100230291/designcardmodel.cpp#L152

Comment: @gil9red спасибо  работает. Но только оно  в трех сol записывается. а мне нужно чтобы  только в в первой сol

Comment: Уточните Col или Row? Кст закомментировали insertRows?

Comment: @gil9red   то что выделено на картинке. только там нужно - https://d.radikal.ru/d25/1808/31/b25e566f75ef.png

Comment: @gil9red нет не  закомментировал. а нужно?

Comment: не могу посмотреть картинку -- рабочая прокси не пускает. Лучше закомментируйте -- хуже не должно стать

Comment: @gil9red закоментировал.   я имел введу у меня есть  таблица   и в ней 3 col

Comment: |1| 2| 3| и мне нужно чтобы  щаписывало только в 1  а оно  зараз мне вставляет в 1, 2, 3

Comment: и в этих колонках одинаковое значение? В data условие подправьте: `if (role == Qt::DisplayRole && col == 0)`, а то оно для всех полей в строке срабатывает